# LVM or RAID large data more than 2TB.

Tags: lvm, storage

I am using VMware esxi, I need to maintain more than 10TB data cycling. I need some information.

1. we need more 2TB vmdk file, If ext4 support 2TB. in case more than 2TB what can i do ?.
2. In case use 500GB 4 disk after as per usage increase the LV, 
   Its better.

   or
3. Used don't try to do lvm . change in to RAID.

Advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

```
Block size is specified at mkfs time and typically is 4KiB.
```

and here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4

So the max file size in this case is 16TiB

For the question 2 I think the best solution is to have LVM over a (HARDWARE) RAID, you can use all of the disks in the RAID volume and slice and dice them whatever way you like with LVM.

Comment: In the above case how to prevent data lose ?.

Comment: here is the answer: https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/advanced-administration.html `...The scheme that has all but become a standard since RAID and LVM have reached maturity is to ensure data redundancy first by grouping disks in a small number of large RAID arrays, and to use these RAID arrays as LVM physical volumes...`